# how to write API's for entire odoo8 application?

Tags: python, rest, odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10

We have an hr application in odoo8 and want to move the front-end part of the entire application into angular js by using API calls. So :

1. Is there any RESTful services in odoo.
2. If RESTful services not there then how to write API's (it can be a Json call) for entire application.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding there is no documentation of Odoo rest api(you will have to create one if you need by checking the controllers and authentications or there are some paid modules in odoo apps).

But If you are using Odoo8 and angularjs, have a look at this repo for [Odoo angularjs connector](https://github.com/akretion/angular-odoo)

Answer (score 0):

yes, odoo contain api for restfull web services and it called in odoo controllers.
you can create controllers with easy way just by specify route and write function to handle request and render the output in json or html output:ex.

```
 @http.route('/showcase_data',type='json', auth='public',website=True,csrf=False)
 def example_func(self):
    return "Hello"
```

you cant execute this controller by write http://xxxx:8069/showcase_data